# Link a Stylesheet (CSS) outside of the HEAD Tag

Tags: html, css, styles, head

I have seen a number of questions regarding this issue and I have yet to see the response I am looking for. I simply want to know if it is possible to link to an external stylesheet anywhere else other than the HEAD tag.

The reason I ask, is I have to use Confluence to document and the addons our company uses are very basic. I wanted to style my page but the issue is that Confluence innately overrides any HEAD tag and inserts its own. There is no way to get around this without the HTML addon, which my company will not purchase.

To get around this, I have to include a large STYLE tag with all of the styled customizations so it can get fairly long.

I am just looking to see if it is possible and how to link a stylesheet anywhere else in the HTML other than the HEAD tag.  (I am aware that this is not common or good practice, and I also understand the reasons for having the stylesheet in the HEAD tag so please no comments regarding this.)

Comment: Did you try it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to include a stylesheet somewhere else other than `<head>` - precisely, you can place it inside `<body>`. To quote [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link):

> A `<link>` tag can occur **either** in the head element or in the body
>   element (or both), depending on whether it has a link type that is
>   body-ok. For example, the stylesheet link type is body-ok, and
>   therefore a `<link rel="stylesheet">` is permitted in the body.

Comment: Thank you! That is all I needed, I had tried it in the body but it appears that confluence also overrides the body tag. All I did was remove the body tag and left the Link at the top. All works well.

Comment: If MDN says that it is body-ok then I suppose it's believable. Anyway, the HTML 5 spec for the body element says that it is supposed to contain "flow content" (see https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110405/sections.html#the-body-element-0) and the flow content model does not list the link element (see https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110405/content-models.html#flow-content). The style element is listed explicitly there.